# LoadError in ProductsController#show について

Tags: ruby-on-rails

http://qiita.com/jacoyutorius/items/a107ff6c93529b6b393e
こちらの記事を参考にしました。

gem "gmaps4rails"
gem "geocoder"
上記のgemを使い、経度と緯度の値だけを一旦入力し、テスト表示させようとしようとし際に起こった問題です。

Unable to autoload constant Goal_detail, expected/.../right_now/app/models/goal_detail.rb to define it

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

```
create_table "goal_details", force: :cascade do |t|
t.string   "name",           limit: 255
t.string   "info",           limit: 255
t.string   "street_address", limit: 255
t.string   "access",         limit: 255
t.string   "parking",        limit: 255
t.string   "price",          limit: 255
t.string   "use_time",       limit: 255
t.string   "hp",             limit: 255
t.string   "other",          limit: 255
t.string   "description",    limit: 255
t.float    "latitude",       limit: 24
t.float    "longitude",      limit: 24
t.datetime "created_at",                 null: false
t.datetime "updated_at",                 null: false
```

end

上記のようなテーブルです。
原因が突き止められません。

よろしくお願いします。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
@gd = Goal_detail.all
```

ではなく

```
@gd = GoalDetail.all
```

ではないでしょうか？

`GoalDetail`は`models/goal_detail.rb`のクラス名を示しています。
`models/goal_detail.rb` クラス名を一度ご確認ください。

Comment: ご回答ありがとうございます。解消されました。